# mount S3 bucket at docker for creating private registry

Tags: amazon-s3, docker-registry, docker-volume

I run a private registry on UBUNTU 18.04: docker run -d -p 5000:5000 registry The process appeared on my docker process list.
I run the command docker volume ls and it's created locally.
how do I mount the docker registry to the s3 bucket so whenever I push the image it's saved to the s3 bucket